# Can we get comparison operator from user config and compare it with python in fewer steps?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to compare a numeric column in table with any dynamic input condition specified in the config. So the comparison operator may come like `> or >=` and `<= or <` with upper and lower limit values.

Say I have table field `value as 100`

and I may get any 2 comparison operators like `>= and <=` from config file

and any upper and lower limit values like `90 and 110` from config file

Now I have to write a code that compares the value 100 with dynamic config condition like

```
if 90 >= 100 <= 110:
```

How can we achieve this? can we use anything like eval or something?

**UPDATE**:
config file will look like

```
limit_condition = {'>=':90,'<':110}
```

or

```
limit_condition = {'>':90,'<':110}
```

or

```
limit_condition = {'>':90,'<=':110}
```

or

```
limit_condition = {'>=':90,'<=':110}
```

There may be a chance that only upper limit or lower limit alone they can give. So it should adopt for that too!

Comment: What libraries are you assuming? This isn't a question for pure Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the fewer code to do this!

```
all(
        [
            limit_condition['>='] >= 100 if limit_condition.get('>=') else limit_condition['>'] > 100 if limit_condition.get('>') else True,
            limit_condition['<='] <= 100 if limit_condition.get('<=') else limit_condition['<'] < 100 if limit_condition.get('<') else True
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Still another one:

```py
ops = {
       "<": lambda a, b: a < b,
       ">": lambda a, b: a > b,
       "<=": lambda a, b: a <= b,
       ">=": lambda a, b: a >= b,
       "==": lambda a, b: a == b
       }        

config = {'>=': 90,'<': 110}
numbers = [80, 100, 120]

for n in numbers:
    if all([ops[op](n, c) for op, c in config.items()]):
        print(f"{n} is ok")
    else:
        print(f"{n} is nok")
```

Comment: Yeah this suits

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to define a comparison function that depends on the config file:

```py
def create_comparison_function(config):
    # analyse configuration
    def comp_fun(number):
        # define operation depending on config; example result:
        return c1 <= number
    return comp_fun
```

Then use this method to create your comparison function and use it

```py
comp_fun = create_comparison_function(config)
for n in numbers:
   if comp_fun(n):
        # do something
   else:
        # do something else
```

Comment: seems fine. But Im looking for simpler steps without extra method def since python is simple to write complex expressions right